# .htaccess url rewrite rule redirects non existing pages to a page it should not to

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have an URL Rewrite rule in .thaccess that does exactly what I want it to:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ /page.php?id=$1 [L]
```

So requests to `www.site.com/page.php?id=one` are redirected to this: `www.site.com/one`, which is what is needed.

However, there is a problem - if any of the other filenames in the main dir is misspelled then the browser redirects to `www.site.com/page.php?id=`

So for example if the name of `www.site.com/other.php` is misspelled with anything like `www.site.com/otherr.php`, then the .htaccess rule kicks in and the URL the user sees is `www.site.com/otherr.php`, while the content showing is the one of `page.php`.

Any ideas what in the rewrite rule needs to be changed to remediate this problem?

Comment: handle non-existent content within your page.php or you will have to list every single page that needs to redirect if you do not wish to redirect everything that is not an existent file or folder as your rule is at the moment.

Comment: @Prix, this is actually what I am doing right now - any non existent requests to `page.php` are redirected to `no_record_found.php`. However, I want to change the rule so that `otherr.php` is redirected straight to `no_record_found.php`, instead of first to `page.php` and then to `no_record_found.php`.

Comment: Then you will have to create a rule for each(or one that can accommodate all) of the valid URL's you want to redirect instead of having the above rule and then you can just use [ErrorDocument with your error page for all the 404.](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/custom-error.html#configuration)

Comment: The solution is to redirect 404 within your page.php for bad id. But you can also reduce the problem by improving the regex expression in .htaccess. For example if you have no id of over 10 characters or less than 3, no numbers, no uppercase or other dashes, dots, etc. Add it in your question if you're interested.